# Get Audio File Uri From File Chooser

Tags: android, audio, path, uri

I need help creating a file chooser that gets the path of the audio file selected as a Uri.

This is what I'm currently using as my file chooser:

```
public void selectedAudio() {
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setType("audio/*");  
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Sound File"), 1);
}
```

But I have no idea how to get the path of the file selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the onActivityResult() method call the passed Intent's getData() method and then getPath:

> String filePath = data.getData().getPath();